# How to Integrate Amazon SQS and Amazon RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-sqs

I want to create a mysql table in AWS rds and then send data from AWS sqs to created table in AWS rds.

Comment: Sadly your question is unclear and lacks any relevant details.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you experiencing a _specific_ problem?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that your requirement is to take information from **a message sent to an Amazon SQS queue** and **insert it into a specific table** in an Amazon RDS MySQL database.

To do this, you would need to **create an AWS Lambda function** that is triggered by the Amazon SQS queue. The function (that you must write) would then connect to the MySQL database and use an `INSERT` statement to insert the data into the desired table.

Assuming that the database is in a private subnet of a VPC, make sure you connect the Lambda function to **the same VPC** so that it can communicate with the database.